# Adjust the size of the view to the given space

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

I'm working on a custom view, which should have equal height and width.

I draw it in the following way:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, getWidth() / 2, mPaint);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    widthMeasureSpec = heightMeasureSpec;

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

If I just add one view onto the screen, the width/height is ok. Though, if I add two of these views next to each other, the size of the views should be adjusted (each view: half width of the screen).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <at.guger.widget.Light
        android:id="@+id/lights_light1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <at.guger.widget.Light
        android:id="@+id/lights_light2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to let the views take as much space as it can, but constrained them from the parent layoutmanager ? You can implement it with a recyclerview and your own LayoutManager overloading the measureChild method so that it would return the widthscreen divided by the number of elememnt in your adapter. Not a working example but something along the lines:

```
// setting up your recycler view
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mView.findViewById(R.id.recycler);

// attaching your custom adapter
mRecyclerAdapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), this); 
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(statusRecyclerAdapter);

// setting the layoutmanager
mRecyclerLayoutManager = new MyRecyclerLayoutManager(
                                 getActivity(),
                                 LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mRecyclerLayoutManager);
```

Then you would create an innerclass MyRecyclerLayoutManager as follow:

```
private class MyRecyclerLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

        MyRecyclerLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
            super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
        }

        public void measureChild(View child, int widthUsed, int heightUsed) {
            super.measureChild(child, widthUsed, heightUsed);
            DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
            int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int) Math.round(displaymetrics.widthPixels / mRecyclerAdapter.size()), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

            final RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            final int heightSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(getHeight(), getHeightMode(),
                    getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom() + heightUsed, lp.height,
                    canScrollVertically());

            child.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
        }

        public void measureChildWithMargins(View child, int widthUsed, int heightUsed) {
            super.measureChildWithMargins(child, widthUsed, heightUsed);
            DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
            int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int) Math.round(displaymetrics.widthPixels * 0.85), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

            final RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            final int heightSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(getHeight(), getHeightMode(),
                    getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom() + heightUsed, lp.height,
                    canScrollVertically());

            child.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
        }
    }
```

Here the important bit is at widthSpec which is window width divided by your recycleradapter size.